# Showing Dojo charts On OpenLayers Map

Tags: openlayers-2, dojo, chart

I am trying to show dojo GFXLayer of dojox.geo.openklayers on my map layers , the problem is that my map is not showing townLayer but map is showing default OSM Layer and GFX layer.What I am Doing Wrong?
My Code Is

```
var dojoMap = new Map("map");  
var map = dojoMap.getOLMap();  
var townLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Towns","http://"localhost":6666/geoserver/wms?",
   {layers: 'Layer:towns', format: 'image/png', transparent: true, info_format: 'text/html',
    gtype:'polygon'});  

map.addLayer(townLayer);  
var layer = new GfxLayer();  
var p = new Point({x:ny.longitude, y:ny.latitude});  
var f = new GeometryFeature(p);  
f.setFill([ 0, 128, 128 ]);  
f.setStroke([ 0, 0, 0 ]);  
f.setShapeProperties({r : 20});  
layer.addFeature(f);  
dojoMap.addLayer(layer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should your code maybe be

```
dojoMap.addLayer(townLayer);
```

instead of

```
map.addLayer(townLayer);
```

Comment: thanks, but in my case that was projection issue